# I received a searchView sample source and am studying code. There are some things I don't understand, so I seek your advice

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, searchview

I received a searchView sample source and am studying code.
What I found is a sample code that I received from

https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-search-in-recyclerview-using-kotlin/

There are some things I don't understand, so I seek your advice.

Related sources are
https://github.com/johncodeos-blog/SearchRecyclerViewExample

from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".DetailsActivity">
</activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is there a reason why Detail Activity.xml should be read first?

In the Main Activity.kt file,

```
    val searchIcon = binding.countrySearch.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_mag_icon)
    searchIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE)


    val cancelIcon = binding.countrySearch.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_close_btn)
    cancelIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE)

    val textView = binding.countrySearch.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.search_src_text)
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

In (R.id.search_mag_icon), (R.id.search_close_btn), and (R.id.search_src_text) do not have to be declared separately?
I couldn't find the declared part, so I wonder where you referred to it.

```
private fun getListOfCountries(){  }
```

Please explain the codes of .

from RecyclerViewAdapter.kt

```
class CountryHolder(var viewBinding: RecyclerviewRowBinding) :     
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewBinding.root)
override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults 
override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?)
```

Please explain this code.

from DetailsActivity.kt

```
intent.extras!!.getString("passselectedcountry")!!
```

Please explain this code.

Comment: Are you new to android development? Since when you are working on android?

Comment: Thank you for your interest.  - AgentP

Did you expect too many questions from me? Then I'm sorry.
I've been studying Android development for about six months.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no difference in what sequence you declare the activities in the Manifest file, so `DetailsActivity` also can be after the `MainActivity`
2. The ids are taken from the layout files (try to find it in `activity_main.xml` or `activity_details.xml`)
3. It seems to be some filtering callbacks, need more context.
4. It's just getting data from intent params (you pass them from one activity to another while navigation)